# python "incrementing" a character string?

Tags: java, python, character

I know in java, if you have a char variable, you could do the following:

```
char a = 'a'
a = a + 1
System.out.println(a)
```

This would print 'b'. I don't know the exact name of what this is, but is there any way to do this in python?

Comment: In Java, a `char` value is essentially the same as an unsigned 16-bit integer. So, incrementing it is really just incrementing it. However, Python does not treat characters interchangeably with integers.

Comment: To elaborate on what Greg said, how would you increment "I am a string"?  Because that's what a 'char' is in Python: a string that happens to have length 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: How can I increment a char?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156892/python-how-can-i-increment-a-char)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use ord and chr :

```
print(chr(ord('a')+1))
# b
```

More information about [ord](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#ord) and [chr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#chr).

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative,

if you actually need to move over the alphabet like in your example, you can use `string.lowercase` and iterate over that:

```
from string import lowercase

for a in lowercase:
    print a
```

see http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string-constants for more

Answer (score 1):

Above solutions wont work when char is z and you increment that by 1 or 2,

Example: if you increment z by incr (lets say incr = 2 or 3) then  (chr(ord('z')+incr)) does not give you incremented value because ascii value goes out of range.

for generic way you have to do this

```
i = a to z any character
incr = no. of increment
#if letter is lowercase
asci = ord(i)
if (asci >= 97) & (asci <= 122):            
  asci += incr
  # for increment case
  if asci > 122 :
    asci = asci%122 + 96
    # for decrement case
    if asci < 97:
      asci += 26
    print chr(asci)
```

it will work for increment or decrement both.

same can be done for uppercase letter, only asci value will be changed.