# Returning the value of an index in a python list based on other values

Tags: python

I have put the letters a-z in a list. How would I find the value of an item in the list depending on what the user typed?

For example if they type the letter `a` it would return `c`, `f` would return `h` and `x` would return `z`.

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
newletters = []

offset = 2

userInput = input('type a string')
newvalue = chr(ord(userInput)+offset)
split = list(newvalue)
print split
```

the above works for a character but not for a string..help?!

Comment: show your attempts...

Comment: @AvinashRaj apologies. have done now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: How can I increment a char?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156892/python-how-can-i-increment-a-char)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
>>> offset = 2
>>> aString = raw_input("digit a letter: ")
>>> aString
'a'
>>> chr(ord(aString)+offset)
'c'
```

documentation:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord

---

If you want to iterate over an entire string, a simple way is using a `for` loop. I assume the input string is always lowercase.

EDIT2: I improved the solution to handle the case when a letter is `'y'` or `'z'` and without "rotation" should begin a not alphabetic character, eg:

```
# with only offset addiction this return a non-alphabetic character
>>> chr(ord('z')+2)
'|'

# the 'z' rotation return the letter 'b'
>>> letter = "z"
>>> ord_letter = ord(letter)+offset
>>> ord_letter_rotated = ((ord_letter - 97) % 26) + 97
>>> chr(ord_letter_rotated)
'b'
```

The code solution:

```
offset = 2
aString = raw_input("digit the string to convert: ")
#aString = "abz"
newString = ""

for letter in aString:
    ord_letter = ord(letter)+offset
    ord_letter_rotated = ((ord_letter - 97) % 26) + 97
    newString += chr(ord_letter_rotated)

print newString
```

The output of this code for the entire lowercase alphabet:

```
cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab
```

Note: you can obtain the lowercase alphabet for free also this way:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

See the wikipedia page to learn something about `ROT13`:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13

Comment: ok this is good. do you know how to do this for a whole string?

Comment: You can add a `for` loop.  Now I modify the solution.

Comment: this is very good. just how would you get around spaces, punctuation and 'y' and 'z' that end the alphabet?

Comment: You can avoid `if` doing `ord_letter = ((ord(letter)+offset - 97) % 26) + 97`.

Comment: Correct, @Ale! I tried to use `mod` before to see I need to add `97` (the `ord` value of `'a'`)... And after I haven't tried. Thank you!

Comment: @Alex.S please explain more. what is letter representing and i have this, what do i need to add? `for i in user_input: new_string = ((ord(letter)+offset - 97) % 26) + 97`

Comment: I added an explanation about using `%`, I hope now it's clear. See [wikipedia ROT13 page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) for a little more theory.

Answer (score 1):

What should happen for `z`? Should it become `b`?

You can use Python's [`maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=maketrans#string.maketrans) and [`translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=maketrans#string.translate) functions to do this as follows:

```
import string

def rotate(text, by):
    s_from = string.ascii_lowercase
    s_to = string.ascii_lowercase[by:] + string.ascii_lowercase[:by]
    cypher_table = string.maketrans(s_from, s_to)
    return text.translate(cypher_table)

user_input = raw_input('type a string: ').lower()
print rotate(user_input, 2)
```

This works on the whole string as follows:

```
type a string: abcxyz
cdezab
```

**How does it work?**

If you print `s_from` and `s_to` they look as follows:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab
```

`maketrans` creates a mapping table to map characters in `s_from` to `s_to`. `translate` then applies this mapping to your string.